# SQL Query accept a valid argument C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, arguments

I have created a database and have presented the data in a gridview using Visual Studio C#. I am trying to write a query method that will search for an employee's name and return all results that are similar to the name.

```
SELECT personID, name, address, phoneNumer, age FROM dbo.person WHERE name Like @name
```

Any advice/help on this would be hugely appreciated. I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: When I try to execute my form application using : 


        private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            this.personTableAdapter.searchName(this.personDataSet.person, searchTextBox.Text);


        }

with a valid name, nothing appears?

Comment: ..."when I try to execute my application using this code".....what happens?  What is the exact error?  Does your application compile, or is it failing at runtime?  The error in the screenshot you posted refers to data types of "text" not being compatible with equal to --- what is that referring to, especially considering the query you wrote in your original question has no equal signs?

Comment: since changing the SQL query to "FROM dbo.person WHERE name Like @name" the error message did not display and I was able to create the method. However, now the problem is that when I run the application, and enter a valid name, it returns nothing, when it should return a value. I enter "Tina" which existed in the gridview's data, but an empty row appeared.

Comment: Have you tried to execute query in SSMS? is it returning row? How did you make gridView, what's the DataSource property?

Comment: The DataSource property is from an added database. I made the gridview by assigning 'GridView' to the data source and dragging it onto a form. When run, the gridview appears with the data, but when "Tina" is entered in the searchTextBox.Text and the search button is clicked, an empty row appears. It should display Tina's details.

Comment: Can you show us your **C# code** that is calling this SQL query?? And please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LIKE clause uses wildcards to substitute letters. One of the most used wild cards is % which translates to 'anything can go in here', so when your LIKE clause looks like this:

```
SELECT personID, name, address, phoneNumer, age FROM dbo.person WHERE name Like 'Tina%'
```

It will retrieve all records that have a name that starts with Tina, while this one:

```
SELECT personID, name, address, phoneNumer, age FROM dbo.person WHERE name Like '%Tina%'
```

This will retrieve all records that have Tina anywhere. By default this is case insensitive I believe, unless you change your DB's collation.

So make the value in your @name parameter include a wildcard somewhere, unless you want to look for an *exact* match.

Comment: So your suggestion is : 

SELECT personID, name, address, phoneNumer, age FROM dbo.person WHERE name Like @name%

?

Comment: No. Put the wildcard in the *value* of `@name`. Alternatively you can concatanate the wildcard to the parameter: `LIKE @name + '%'`